# How can I make Zenoss recognize skin changes?

Tags: python, zope, zenoss

I'm writing a ZenPack for Zenoss which includes a new DataSource.  The DataSource has a ToOne relationship with another persistent object and I'm trying to construct the user interface to allow a user to specify the value of this relationship.  I've given the DataSource a factory_type_information attribute with an "immediate_view" key mapped to the name of a skin/template - "viewAgentScriptDataSource".  In my ZenPack's skins directory, I created viewAgentScriptDataSource.pt.  Zenoss seems to have liked this and now when I view an instance of the DataSource, I see a page based on viewAgentScriptDataSource.pt.

However, after this first success, any edits I make to the skin/template file are ignored.  I tried replacing the dummy content of the file with something more realistic and reloading the data source view.  The dummy content still appears.  I tried restarting Zenoss and reloading the view.  The dummy content still appears.  I tried deleting my ZenPack and re-installing it.  The dummy content still appears.

How do I get Zenoss to load the new contents of the skin file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that none of the template changes I made actually had any impact on the final page output.  The changes were picked up, they just didn't matter.